# Issue with UIScrollView starting in different position iPhone vs iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

My project is set up to be Universal. I have a view in which a ScrollView fills (and exceeds) the view size. It's larger vertically, so that the contents scroll up/down. When I run this on any iPhone simulator version (4.2...5.x, and retina) the ScrollView starts with the contents at the top - the way I want it to. However when I run it on the iPad simulator (any version) the contents start at the bottom - reverse of the iPhone.

I've read several threads and I've tried using `scrollRectToVisible` and `scrollContentOffset` but they both are quite annoying to see (animated or not). I've tried them in `viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear` and it always looks annoying as you can see the contents shift after the view appears.

The scrollwview and it's contents are added via the IB. For the iPhone, both are positioned correctly in the IB. For the iPad I change the size and content size of the scrollview in 'viewDidLoad' like so:

```
[helpScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1200)];
tmpFrame=helpScroll.frame;
tmpFrame.size.height=1004;
helpScroll.frame=tmpFrame;
```

Does anyone know why the iPad seems reversed from the iPhone and how to fix this?

Comment: "larger vertically" ? is this an oxymoron?

Comment: You have failed to say anything about how the scrollview gets into the interface in the first place - and how it acquires its subviews, and how its content size gets set. You show no code, you give no details. If you want help, describe / expose what you're *doing*.

Comment: oxymoron? No - an oxymoron is two words that appear to be opposite (military intelligence) while vertical is a direction, and larger is a comparison of size.

Comment: @matt Sorry - many times these things are specific to the device so I don't always add code right away. I've edited my original post with more details.

Comment: Still too fuzzy. "I have a view in which a ScrollView fills (and exceeds) the view size. It's larger vertically, so that the contents scroll up/down". What on earth does that mean? Why does the scroll view exceed its container's size? What does the size of the scroll view have to do with which way it scrolls? Unless you can use language accurately, distinguishing the basic notions such as scroll view, contentSize, superview, etc., the words of the question remain uncommunicative.

Comment: @matt21 Do you have to be so condescending? It should be obvious I'm learning. As for my language, I can communicate quite well - your own questions indicate you understand me - "Why does the ScrollView exceed it's container's size?" You obviously understand my statement that it's larger vertically so I must be communicating well enough. Why is it that way? Because I laid it out in IB and left it that way. I didn't know it would be a problem since I change it in code. Perhaps instead of trying to belittle me, you could just ask your questions and I can answer them. Otherwise, please move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I had followed a tutorial which added items (ImageView, TextView, etc.) directly to the ScrollView and this caused problems when I resized the ScrollView. I found another tutorial which recommended using a View to hold the contents, then adding the View as a sub-view to the ScrollView. This works perfectly.

Here's the other tutorial: http://redartisan.com/2010/5/23/scrolling-with-uiscrollview